# Qual a melhor forma de publicar minha aplicação C# Asp.NET no Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-azure

Comecei um projeto na faculdade e estou usando o Azure para hospedá-la. Esse é meu primeiro contato com essa ferramente e estou tendo grande dificuldades para entendê-la. Já procurei tutoriais e explicações no grande google, mas só acho coisas antigas e a ferramenta está mais aprimorada agora. Quando eu faço a publicação da minha aplicação pela primeira vez no Visual Studio, tudo ocorre normalmente, mas na segunda já acusa erro no Web.config. E percebo que quando eu apago uma tela no meu projeto e faço a publicação, a página que eu publiquei antes continua hospedada no Azure. Essa é a primeira vez que trabalho com uma aplicação C# Asp.NET, se tiverem mais dicas ou conselhos, serei muito grato ;)

Answer (score 4):

> Qual a melhor forma de publicar minha aplicação C# Asp.NET no Azure?

Usando Web Deploy. É um método embutido dentro da interface do Visual Studio. Basta baixar o perfil de publicação do Azure e importar na sua solução.

> Quando eu faço a publicação da minha aplicação pela primeira vez no Visual Studio, tudo ocorre normalmente, mas na segunda já acusa erro no Web.config. E percebo que quando eu apago uma tela no meu projeto e faço a publicação, a página que eu publiquei antes continua hospedada no Azure.

Sim, o Web Deploy não apaga os arquivos antigos por padrão.

[Você pode usar o WebMatrix](https://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) para fazer a exclusão de arquivos não mais necessários.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu queria saber. Muito obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 3):

Apenas complementado a resposta do @Cigano.

Realmente, por padrão, o método de WebDeploy não apaga arquivos antigos, porém há uma configuração, simples.

Na janela de "Publish Web", na aba "Settings", sob o grupo "File Publish Options", marque a opção "Remove additional files at destination".

[image: Publish Web / Settings / File Publish Options / Remove additional files at destination]

Assim, a cada procedimento de deploy, os arquivos não mais referenciados pelos seu projetos serão eliminados.

PS: Isso não vale para a pasta "App_Data", tanto que, para limpar esta, existe um checkbox dedicado.

Comment: Às vezes o arquivo nem vai atrapalhar o que estou fazendo, mas mesmo assim me incomoda saber que ele está lá ocupando espaço haha Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @MarcoVinicius, somos dois. rs.